# Angular HTML templating - How can I use the current value of a number input as the upper bound for my array slice?

Tags: angular

This is probably super simple but I can't figure it out. I have a number input, and I want to use the current value of that number input to display/hide a certain number of items in a list. template looks like this:

```
<input type="number" value="10" step="10" min="10" style="width: 4em" (change)="showNThings = this.value">
...
<div *ngFor="let item of myArray | slice:0:showNThings">
```

Initially it seems like this code works (10 items are displayed) but I think only because `this.value` is referencing the `value` attribute of the input tag. Items are not displayed/hidden when I manipulate the input number. How do I assign the CURRENT value of the input to my `showNThings` variable?

Comment: That was it! Please make this comment an answer if you want credit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two-way to data binding.

the first way is

When typing into the input, the input’s value is written into the username model and then reflected back into the view, resulting in a nice greeting.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="username">
<p>Hello {{username}}!</p>
```

and the second way is

```
<input [value]="username" (input)="username = $event.target.value">
<p>Hello {{username}}!</p>
```

**[value]="username"** - Binds the expression username to the input element's value property

**(input)="expression"** - Is a declarative way of binding an expression to the input element’s input event (yes there's such event)

**username = $event.target.value** - The expression that gets executed when the input event is fired

**$event** - Is an expression exposed in event bindings by Angular, which has the value of the event’s payload

[Two-way Data Binding in Angular](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html)

Answer (score 0):

**working demo** : [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dy1tbf)

You can also do it using `*ngFor's` index property and `*ngIf`. Using them together you can achieve it. First in `*ngFor` pick the current iteration number using `index` then use `*ngIf` where you can check that iteration number should be less than limit number. If it satisfies above condition then only show the inner `<div>` Like shown below.

> app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor = "let item of arr; let i = index;">
    <div *ngIf="i<limit">ITEM NUMBER : {{item}}<div>
</div>
```

> app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
limit=4;
   arr:number[]=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
   clickHanler(val:number){
        this.limit = val;
   }
}
```